# SAP Hana Service Layer Error "Unknown entity" accessing the service via Postman

Tags: sapui5, hana

I created the "UDO" & "UDT", register it using object registration wizard but whenever I try to access the table via Service Layer I am getting the following error can you one please let me know some solution on this :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": -1000,
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-us",
            "value": "Unknown entity."
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart the service, and try again

```
/etc/init.d/b1s restart
```

Answer (score 1):

**Stop the service** for about 2 minutes and then start it again:

/etc/init.d/b1s stop

...

/etc/init.d/b1s start